# Using quosures within vars argument of mutate_at

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rlang

I would like to write a simple function that would make use of the quosures passed via ellipsis in `mutate_at` call.

```
# Packages
sapply(
    X = c("dplyr", "rlang"),
    FUN = require,
    character.only = TRUE
)

# Data
set.seed(1)
cbind(as.data.frame(replicate(3, replicate(
    10, paste0(sample(letters, 5), collapse = "")
))), c(1:10)) %>% setNames(nm = paste(replicate(4, "col"), LETTERS[1:4], sep = "_")) -> dta


# Mutate
mutate_some <- function(df, ...) {
    mut_vars <- quos(...)
    df %>%
        mutate(.vars = !!!mut_vars,
               .funs = funs(toupper(.)))
}

# test
dta %>% mutate_some(col_A, col_C)
```

## Problem

The code produces:

```
>> dta %>% mutate_some(col_A, col_C)
   col_A col_B col_C col_D .vars1 .vars2       .funs
1  gjnue mvkfb rigwn     1  gjnue  rigwn ~toupper(.)
2  xzpob chmpi fdlvn     2  xzpob  fdlvn ~toupper(.)
3  feqix xhlyo zsijd     3  feqix  zsijd ~toupper(.)
4  mrxiy glsbt arcko     4  mrxiy  arcko ~toupper(.)
5  yfpcz iuzhk zmldq     5  yfpcz  zmldq ~toupper(.)
6  kajuh xvjry lmefn     6  kajuh  lmefn ~toupper(.)
7  moles lrjhq obazu     7  moles  obazu ~toupper(.)
8  rtcqj frczd pomwl     8  rtcqj  pomwl ~toupper(.)
9  vqsml gbpur rpfxq     9  vqsml  rpfxq ~toupper(.)
10 ualqp uljsn lerct    10  ualqp  lerct ~toupper(.)
```

## Desired results

The results should be equivalent to:

```
dta %>% mutate_at(.funs = funs(toupper(.)), .vars = c("col_A", "col_C"))
   col_A col_B col_C col_D
1  GJNUE mvkfb RIGWN     1
2  XZPOB chmpi FDLVN     2
3  FEQIX xhlyo ZSIJD     3
4  MRXIY glsbt ARCKO     4
5  YFPCZ iuzhk ZMLDQ     5
6  KAJUH xvjry LMEFN     6
7  MOLES lrjhq OBAZU     7
8  RTCQJ frczd POMWL     8
9  VQSML gbpur RPFXQ     9
10 UALQP uljsn LERCT    10
```

---

## Assumptions:

- The `mutate_some` function has to take the ellipsis argument that is lates used in `mut_vars <- quos(...)`.
- In particular, I'm looking for a solution that will resemble `rlang::do_something_(mut_vars)`. This function is a part of a longer pipeline and I need to keep `mut_vars` as `quos()` as I'm using it later on.
- I don't want to change column names (as in desired results above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already be aware of the `mutate_at` function and i'm not sure why you are not using it in your `mutate_some`, but it produces the results you want

```
mutate_some <- function(df, ...) {
  mut_vars <- quos(...)
  df %>%
    mutate_at(mut_vars,
           .funs = funs(toupper(.)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I don't have to break the quosures and can just pass `mut_vars` without **`!!!`** or **`rlang::(...)`**. Concerning your question, the example is synoptic. In my actual pipeline I've other operations that I apply frequently so it made sense to wrap them in a common function. Naturally, there would be no point to wrap `mutate_at` in `mutate_some` without other functions.